# How to use FOS UserId in other Entity

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to save the userid value into my new entity RDV, when i try to do this :

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getId();
$rdv->setUserid($user);
```

This is my RDV Entity :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade=
       {"persist"})
     */
private $userid;
```

I get this error :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to CMRBundle\Entity\RDV::setUserid() must be an instance of UserBundle\Entity\User, integer given, called in C:\wamp64\www\No\src\CMRBundle\Controller\AdvertController.php
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$rdv->setUserid($user);
```

Because you need to add an entity not the id in a relation

---

I suggest to you to change your field into `private $user;` so you can use `$rdv->setUser($user);` where is more clear for your domain